# PowerShell: Check which ADUser has the Logon script "SLOGIC"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, multiple-users

I've got the task to write a script in PowerShell to read out if a User has the Logon script "SLOGIC". With this code I'm able to get the information for a single User:

```
Write-Host "Checking for logon scripts."
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the username"
Write-Host "Checking for logon script."
$ScriptPath = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties Scriptpath | Select ScriptPath


If ($ScriptPath) {
  Write-Host "$User'has a logon script"
  Write-host $ScriptPath

  }  Else {

  Write-Host "$User' does not have a logon script"

}
```

The code spits out this:

```
Checking for logon scripts.
Input the username: u002533
Checking for logon script.
u002533'has a logon script
@{ScriptPath=SLOGIC}
```

I need a command to give me a list of all Users, because I have to check this with over 500 Users. (and I don't want to do this with 500 Users manually)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to write 2-3 lines of text to the screen per user, or do you want to export the data to a CSV or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter` parameter(s) with `Get-ADUser` to retrieve only the ones that has the given term in their `ScriptPath` attribute:

```
$scriptPathFilter = '*SLOGIC*'
Get-ADUser -Filter {scriptPath -like $scriptPathFilter} -Properties ScriptPath |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "User '$($_.SAMAccountName)' has logon script '$($_.ScriptPath)'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a diffrent answer to my Problem. I used this Script:

import-module activedirectory
Get-ADUser -filter {(scriptpath -like "SLOGIC")}